# Pytorch 2D Feature Tensor 1D output Same weights across dimension

Tags: python, pytorch

I am handeling a timeseries dataset with n timesteps, m features and k objects.
As a result my feature vector has a shape of (n,k,m) While my targets shape is (n,m)

I want to predict the targets for every timestep and object, but with the same weights for every opject. Also my loss function looks like this.

```
average_loss = loss_func(prediction, labels)
sum_loss = loss_func(sum(prediction), sum(labels))
loss = loss_weight * average_loss + (1-loss_weight) * sum_loss
```

My plan is to not only make sure, that I predict every item as good as possible, but also that the sum of all items get perdicted. loss_weights is a constant.

Currently I am doing this kind of ugly solution:

```
features = local_batch.squeeze(dim = 0)
labels = torch.unsqueeze(local_labels.squeeze(dim = 0), 1)
prediction = net(features)
```

I set my batchsize = 1. And squeeze it to make the k objects my batch.

My network looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden)   # hidden layer
    self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)   # output layer

def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
    x = self.predict(x)             # linear output
    return x
```

How do I make sure I do a reasonable convolution over the opject dimension in order to keep the same weights for all objects, without commiting to batchsize=1? Also, how do I achieve the same loss function, where I compute the loss of the prediction sum vs target sum for any timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly ugly -- I would do the same but generalize it a bit for batch size >1 using `view`.

```py
# Using your notations
n, k, m = features.shape
features = local_batch.view(n*k, m)
prediction = net(features).view(n, k, m)
```

With the prediction in the correct shape (`n*k*m`), implementing your loss function should not be difficult.